# Does react production build automatically compresses vidoes and images files?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have created a react application which is right now deployed with the production build.

```
yarn run build
serve -S build
```

Well I know it compresses the `.js` and `.scss` files and creates a build folder then serve.

The issue is does it compresses the images & videos files as well? If not how can I do that? because the project I am working on has a lot's of images & vidoes files which impacts a lot on performance and loads the page very slowly.

Kindly help with this...

Comment: videos and images typically do not benefit from compression as they are already heavily compressed formats - of course, you could determine if the build is compressing these further, by checking the file size yourself!!! not sure how they could be used in a browser if they are not valid image/video files now that some arbitrary process has compressed them using some arbitrary compression algorithm  though

Answer (score 1, accepted):

React doesn't do those stuff. It is just a framework for development.

It is the web server's responsibility to handle those stuff, i.e. `serve` in your case.

But even that, it is a common practice that web servers don't apply additional compression to assets (fonts, images, videos, audios, etc.), because they are already compressed in the first place.

Take images as an example, common file formats like JPG, PNG, WEBP are compressed. Unless you are serving BMP or RAW, which you shouldn't, there is no point for web servers to apply any compressions to them.